# Can I transform a few features to polynomial in multi regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, polynomial

Let's say I have 3 features in my ols model as below.

```
model = sm.ols(formula='y ~ a + b + c', data=df)
```

**Question 1.** If I want to transform the feature 'a' as polynomial 3 degree, then should I just add I(a**2) and I(a**3)?

**Question 2.** What about if I want to transform the feature 'a' as 3 degree and the feature 'b' as 2 degree.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question 1 sounds correct, and that same idea would apply to question 2. Polynomials usually have an offset term, and you should have one in this case.

Comment: Thanks, James. Do you mean I should add one  constant on exog as part of features?

Comment: Yes. The docs at https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html discuss "hasconst" to let the software know that the formula includes a constant (offset) term on the Right Hand Side (RHS in the docs).

Comment: Got it. Cheers!